# Converting Raster to new projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, epsg

I received an ECW file from a local City Hall that was created on EPSG 6893.

I need a way to convert it to EPSG 3844 so we can use it in Autocad MAP3D. But I am not able to find a way to export the prj file for the new raster position with QGIS.

Comment: Which GIS-software are you working with?

Comment: QGIS version 3.26

Comment: Have you had a look at the [official QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html?highlight=raster%20reprojection#source-properties), esp. the following quote "If you wish to reproject your data, use a reprojection algorithm from Processing or Save it as new dataset"?

Comment: EPSG:6893 is a Compound Coordinate System, which is not defined in Map 3D's MAPCSLIBRARY. Using MAPCONNECT, Edit Coordinate System to EPSG:3844.

Comment: [Warp](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html?highlight=warp#warp-reproject) it